# PHP: takes the value from the old form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm writing an exam code. In the form I'm calling a method that generates questions and store the students answer.

My problem is that in the form when I store the student answer in the database the answer of the previous question is stored in the current student answer field. And then even when the student answer is right it'll be always wrong according to the code I wrote.

I feel that the problem is that I am putting the inset query inside the display function that displays the question but I don't know how to fix it or where to put the insert query.

Example:

Q1:the student answer is 4.
   the student answer field in the database is stored as null.

Q2:the student answer is 9.
   the student answer field in the database is stored as 4.

Q3:the student answer is 2.
   the student answer field in the database is stored as 9.

In the form I called method(1) thet calls method (2) and method (3).

method (2):

```
function display($sec, $level, $operation, $x, $y, $EvalOrExam, $Answers, $stdAnswer, $result)
 {
$examID;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM question WHERE  Qsec='$sec' and QlawID='$operation' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$Qbody = $data['Qtext'] . $x . $data['Qtext2'] . $y . $data['Qtext3'];
echo '<div dir=\'rtl\'>' . $Qbody . '</div>';
echo '<br/>';
return $Qbody;
 }
```

method (3):

```
  function storeExamQ($sec, $level,$EvalOrExam, $Answers, $stdAnswer, $result,$Qbody)
  {
$Answers = $Answers + 1;

    if ($Answers == '1')
    {
        $sql = "SELECT MAX(examID) FROM exam WHERE stdID='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
        if (!$query) echo "Database Error : " . $sql;
        $query = intval($row['0']);
        $_SESSION['examID'] = $query+1;
    }

        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `exam`(`examID`,`QID`,`stdID`, `examLevel`, `Qbody` , `Qsec` , `stdAnswer` , `correctAnswer` ) VALUES ('" . $_SESSION['examID'] . "','" . $Answers . "','" . $_SESSION['id'] . "','" . $level . "','" . $Qbody . "','" . $sec . "','" . $stdAnswer . "','" . $result . "')";
        $query1 = mysql_query($sql1);
        if (!$query1) echo "Database Error : " . $sql1;
  }
```

The calling inside method (1):

```
  function operations($sec, $levelOfEval, $numOfQ, $EvalOrExam)
 {
if (isset($_POST['result']))
{

    echo '<br/>';
    $stdAnswer = $_POST['stdAnswer'];
    $result = intval($_POST['result']);
    if (!isset($_SESSION['correctAnswers']) AND !isset($_SESSION['wrongAnswers']) AND !isset($_SESSION['Answers']))
    {
        $_SESSION['correctAnswers'] = $correctAnswers = 0;
        $_SESSION['wrongAnswers'] = $wrongAnswers = 0;
        $_SESSION['Answers'] = $Answers = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $correctAnswers = $_SESSION['correctAnswers'];
        $wrongAnswers = $_SESSION['wrongAnswers'];
        $Answers = $_SESSION['Answers'];
    }

    if ($result != $stdAnswer OR $stdAnswer == "")
    {
        $wrongAnswers++;
        $Answers++;
    }
    else if ($result == $stdAnswer)
    {
        $correctAnswers++;
        $Answers++;
    }


    $_SESSION['correctAnswers'] = $correctAnswers;
    $_SESSION['wrongAnswers'] = $wrongAnswers;
    $_SESSION['Answers'] = $Answers;
}

if ($_SESSION['Answers'] < $numOfQ)
{
    echo '<div dir=\'rtl\'>';
    if (isset($_SESSION['correctAnswers']) AND isset($_SESSION['wrongAnswers']) AND isset($_SESSION['Answers']) AND $EvalOrExam == '0')
    {
        echo $correctAnswers;
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $wrongAnswers;
        echo '<br/>';
    }

    echo $Answers + 1;
    echo '<br/>';
    echo '</div>';
    $operation = rand(1, 4); // 1 add, 2 subtract, 3 multiply, 4 divied

     //IF conditions that generate the values of $x and $y

    $Qbody=displayOperations($sec, $levelOfEval, $operation, $x, $y, $EvalOrExam, $Answers, $stdAnswer, $result);
            if ($EvalOrExam == 1)
    {
storeExamQ($sec, $level,$EvalOrExam, $Answers, $stdAnswer, $result,$Qbody);
}
    echo '<br/>';
    return $result;
}
else
{
    if ($EvalOrExam == 0)
    {
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $correctAnswers;
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $wrongAnswers;
        echo '<br/>';
        /*echo "Answers:";
        echo $Answers;*/
        echo '<br/>';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `result`(`resultID`,`stdID`,`secID`, `grade`) VALUES (null,'" . $_SESSION['id'] . "','$sec','" . $correctAnswers . "')";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$query) echo "Database Error : " . $sql;
    }

else if ($EvalOrExam == 1)

{

        $sql = "UPDATE `student` SET `activateExam`=0 WHERE `ID`='". $_SESSION['id'] ."'";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$query) echo "Database Error : " . $sql;
        echo mysql_error();
        unset($_SESSION['examID']);
        unset($_SESSION['operationsCount']);
        unset($_SESSION['shapesCount']);
        unset($_SESSION['calculationsCount']);

}

    $_SESSION['finish'] = '1';
    unset($_SESSION['correctAnswers']);
    unset($_SESSION['wrongAnswers']);
    unset($_SESSION['Answers']);
}
}
```

The Form:

```
  echo '<div>' . $result = evaluation('4', $level,$numOfQ,'1') . '</div>';
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="result" value="' . $result . '">';
```

Method evaluation calls operations that calls both display and store.

Comment: If your function is called `display`, I'd expect it just to display the question - I'd recommend separating out the code that saves the answer into a different function, and calling that just before you call `display`. It'll make things a lot more maintainable.

Comment: I did what you've told me but I still have the problem. I updated the code in the post according to what you said.

Comment: It's really hard to follow your code, because I've no idea what any of the variables are. But if I had to hazard a WAG, you've got this line `$_SESSION['examID'] = $query + 1;` just before you do the INSERT. I'd move it to just after the INSERT.

Comment: Yes I know and I really appreciate that you're trying. By  `$_SESSION['examID'] = $query + 1;` I mean that I want the code to take the last exam id and increment it by one in order to create a new id to the current exam, I don't think It has anything to do with the problem I'm having. Thank you thought.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're going to have to do some more debugging. I can see two `INSERT INTO exam` lines; I assume that those are the ones that are giving you the problem? Can you try and narrow it down? When you submit the first question, where the answer isn't being stored at all, can you echo out the SQL that's writing this to the database? And also flag up which line it is?

Comment: Where is your session_start?

Comment: I edited he code. You were right there is no need to have two queries although it didn't cause the problem because even after I made it one query I still have the issue. The insert query at the first question: ``INSERT INTO `exam`(`examID`,`QID`,`stdID`, `examLevel`, `Qbody` , `Qsec` , `stdAnswer` , `correctAnswer` ) VALUES('109','1','1','','QBody','2','','441')``

Comment: @Mihai at the page that have the form only. the php file that has all the functions has no session_start.

Comment: @user3013190 - then the issue is that `$stdAnswer` isn't being set. I can't see where you're calling `storeexamq()`, though - what is being passed into it?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update method (1) code. storeexamq() is inside method (1). `$stdAnswer` is set at the seventh line of method (1).And about what is passed to storeexamq(): `($sec, $level,$EvalOrExam, $Answers, $stdAnswer, $result,$Qbody)`

Comment: Per the PHP docs, the mysql_* library "is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future." - is there a reason you're not using mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @TiesonT. No, there is not. Actually, it's the first time I know about it. Thank you I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @user3013190 - OK. Look and see where `$stdAnswer` is set - it's coming directly from $_POST. That means that your form is setting the wrong value, I think.

Comment: @andrewsi - yes I know the problem is in posting the value it always takes the previous one. I don't know why.

Comment: Remember that each INSERT creates a new record. Is that what you intend? If not, are you deleting the old record at some point? Perhaps you want to do an UPDATE or REPLACE operation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, one of your SQL statement is not formed correctly.

After every

```
$sql = ...
```

insert:

```
echo $sql;
```

Then run that SQL in the database directly, and see if you get what you need.

Also, please edit your question to reflect the current code. There are many comments, and it's hard to figure out what's your actual code.

Let me know, if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys so much, I really appreciate the help.

The problem was solved by calling method

```
storeExamQ($sec, $level,$EvalOrExam, $Answers, $stdAnswer, $result,$Qbody);
```

at method (1) directly after the student answer and the result are set.